# Common targets are not recognized by Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ant, build.xml, targets

I have added all common targets like (`init`, `clean`, `getivy`, etc) in `./common/common.xml` and added:

```
<import file="${basedir}/common/common.xml"/>
```

in `build.xml`.

When I build the project, its working fine.  But, When I open build.xml in Eclipse IDE, I see some "Red" marks underneath `targets` which have a dependency targets that are defined in `common.xml`.  And when I do mouse over those Red marked targets, I see a message saying that:

> Target `init` does not exist in this project.

To clarify, the `common` folder is added through `svn:externals`. Does this need extra configurations in Eclipse?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a workaround for this? I'm seeing this issue in my current version of eclipse helios.

Answer (score 2):

I have Eclipse Indigo Service Release 1 Build id: 20110916-0149 with ant 1.8.2 and the described problem with `import` seems to be fixed as Steve already mentioned. But the problem still exists for `include` and no answer seems to solve it for me. I searched the bugtracker shortly but don't have the time to be sure and test in the latest eclipse version and post a bug in the [bugtracker](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=ant+include).

Edit:
I had the problem with `import` again after refactoring the folder structure in the project and moving the buildfile. Although I started "Validate" on the project, the validation cached the old location and did'nt realize the move. I had to close the editor and the warning disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

If your `build.xml`, and the common directory are at the same directory level then just try

```
<import file="common/common.xml" />
```

This works for me fine.

Comment: I tried that one too.
In either of the cases i am able to build the project, but why eclipse is not recognizing the common targets when i open build.xml.

I am using Eclipse ganymede 3.4.2 I also tried in galileo

Answer (score 0):

Use the include path `${basedir}/common/common.xml` because `.` is probably the directory in which Eclipse is installed.

Comment: forgot to mention, i add import file="${basedir}/common/common.xml" in build.xml

Comment: I have a common directory included as an svn:external.  Nearly the same setup as you.  My build file is simply:

    <project name="ProjectName" default="package">
   <import file="common/build/common-targets.xml" />
    </project>

What ANT runtime are you using within eclipse.  I am using 1.7.1.v20090120-1145

Comment: Ah, yes, the Ant runtime could have an effect. Other than that, I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

I found a post online [here](http://marc.info/?l=ant-user&m=127119241304408&w=2) where someone found a workaround. You just need to make the file import not the first line in the ant build file. If you put it after a property declaration for instance the error goes away. This worked fine for me and eclipse is happy now.

> The specific problem we had seemed to be because we
>   were importing common `build.xml` files into our project-specific build files, but the import was having problems when it is the first line in our
>   project-specific build file.
>
> However, if I put a property task before the import, it seems to work fine. I am guessing this much force some initialization that wasn't occurring with only the `<import>`.  I have no idea why this same issue doesn't happen in either command line with Ant 1.8, or with Eclipse using Ant 1.7.